# my rasberry pi (3) doesnt have desktop like everyone else

Tags: pi-3, desktop

i am finding difficulties with my pi not starting up with desktop screen, is it a simple issue or do i need an update (i am connected to wifi) top image is controller i am using, second is screen upon startup[image]

[image]

Comment: What OS are you using. If it's RetroPie you don't get a desktop.

Comment: oh i think it is retropie, thanks that helps me not waste my time trying to figure it out

Comment: If you want the desktop, you can install RetroPie onto Raspbian. There's a guide on the RetroPie website. The RetroPie image (which you maybe using) is supposed to work more like an appliance and boot straight to Emulation Station.

Comment: @mintyfreshpenguin RetroPie IS Rasbpian. It's a collection of packages installed on top of Raspbian.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the LXDE desktop on your RetroPie image:

https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/FAQ#where-did-the-desktop-go

If you want to boot directly to your desktop, go to "RetroPie configuration" (in EmulationStation) and select "raspi-config" and change the boot behavior to desktop (Enable Boot to Desktop/Scratch):

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify a bit, RetroPie is a collection of packages installed on top of Raspbian. There is no need to manually install RetroPie on top of a clean Raspbian image in order to have a "desktop". From RetroPie, you can go to the command line and install any desktop environment that you choose. If you want to replicate a vanilla Raspbian experience, you just need to install the `raspberry-ui-mods` package.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-ui-mods
```